# Does MassTransit Transactional Outbox Work with Multi Bus scenarios

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit, distributed-transactions

There is a situation that I have separate ***CommandBus*** and ***EventBus***, I have a consumer that listens to the commands in the command bus and after the operation is handled it publishes related events to the ***Event Bus***. I want to have the built-in support of the transactional outbox pattern on the ***EventBus***.

[Here is the link to a repo](https://github.com/shahabganji/transactional-outbox)

The following is the configuration of the application:

```cs
 public static void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext host, IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<MessageBrokerConfiguration>(host.Configuration.GetSection("MessageBroker"));
        var brokerConfiguration = new MessageBrokerConfiguration();
        host.Configuration.Bind("MessageBroker", brokerConfiguration);
        
        services.AddHostedService<DatabaseMigratorHostedService>();
        
        services.AddMassTransit<ICommandBus>(mt =>
        {
            mt.UsingRabbitMq((context, configurator) =>
            {
                configurator.Host(brokerConfiguration.CommandBus);
                configurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });

            mt.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<CreateOrderConsumer>();
        });
        
        services.AddMassTransit(mt =>
        {
            mt.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<OrderContext>(options =>
            {
                options.QueryDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                options.UsePostgres();
                options.UseBusOutbox();
            });
            
            mt.UsingRabbitMq((context, configurator) =>
            {
                configurator.Host(brokerConfiguration.EventBus);
                configurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
        });

        services.AddRepositories(host.Configuration);
        services.AddScoped<IEventEmitter, MasstransitEventEmitter>();
    }
```

and the following is my consumer that listens to a command in one bus and publishes an event to another:

```cs
public sealed class CreateOrderConsumer
    : IConsumer<CreateOrder>
{
    private readonly IEventEmitter _eventEmitter;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IRepository<Order> _repository;

    public CreateOrderConsumer(
        IRepository<Order> repository,
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        IEventEmitter eventEmitter)
    {
        _unitOfWork = Guard.Against.Null(unitOfWork);
        _repository = Guard.Against.Null(repository);
        _eventEmitter = Guard.Against.Null(eventEmitter);
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CreateOrder> context)
    {
        var order = new Order(context.Message.ProductId, context.Message.Quantity);
        
        await _repository.StoreAsync(order);
        
        await _eventEmitter.Emit(order.DomainEvents);
        order.ClearDomainEvents();
        
        await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
        await context.RespondAsync<CreateOrderResult>(new { OrderId = order.Id });
    }
```

and my IEventEmitter is getting a IBus:

```cs
public sealed class MasstransitEventEmitter : IEventEmitter
{
    private readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;

    public MasstransitEventEmitter(IBus publishEndpoint)
    {
        _publishEndpoint = Guard.Against.Null(publishEndpoint);
    }
    
    public async Task Emit(IEnumerable<IDomainEvent> domainEvents)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var domainEvent in domainEvents)
            {
                await _publishEndpoint.Publish(domainEvent, domainEvent.GetType(), CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // ignored
        }
    }
}
```

here is the DbContext that is used for the business logic and also transactional outbox configs:

```cs
public sealed class OrderContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public OrderContext(DbContextOptions<OrderContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    internal DbSet<OrderEntity> Orders { get; private set; } = default!;

    public async Task CommitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => await this.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new OrderEntityConfiguration());
        
        modelBuilder.AddInboxStateEntity();
        modelBuilder.AddOutboxMessageEntity();
        modelBuilder.AddOutboxStateEntity();
    }
}
```

There is the API layer that sends commands to the command bus via `IRequestClient<CreateOrder>` and awaits to get a response back. The problem is that when the Event Bus (not command bus) is down, the transactional outbox is not working, and it continues until a time-out exception is happening.

```cs
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(
        [FromBody] CreateOrderDto createOrderDto,
        [FromServices] IRequestClient<CreateOrder> createOrderRequestClient)
    {
        var result = await createOrderRequestClient.GetResponse<CreateOrderResult>(
            new CreateOrder{ ProductId = createOrderDto.ProductId,Quantity= createOrderDto.Quantity }, 
            timeout: RequestTimeout.After(m:2));
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

And the logs for the API:

```bash
info: MassTransit[0]
      Bus started: rabbitmq://localhost/
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7129
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5134
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /Users/shahab/dev/talks/Demo.TransactionalOutbox/Demo.TransactionalOutbox.Api
```

Logs for the Application Layer(Listens to the Commands and Publishes Events):

```bash
[13:33:45 INF] Configured endpoint CancelOrder, Consumer: Demo.TransactionalOutbox.Application.Consumers.CancelOrderConsumer
[13:33:45 INF] Configured endpoint CreateOrder, Consumer: Demo.TransactionalOutbox.Application.Consumers.CreateOrderConsumer
[13:33:45 INF] Configured endpoint GetOrder, Consumer: Demo.TransactionalOutbox.Application.Consumers.GetOrderConsumer
[13:33:49 DBG] Starting bus instances: ICommandBus, IBus
[13:33:49 DBG] Starting bus: rabbitmq://localhost/
[13:33:49 DBG] Starting bus: rabbitmq://localhost:6666/
[13:33:49 DBG] Connect: guest@localhost:5672/
[13:33:49 DBG] Connect: guest@localhost:6666/
[13:33:49 DBG] Connected: guest@localhost:5672/ (address: amqp://localhost:5672, local: 49955)
[13:33:49 DBG] Connected: guest@localhost:6666/ (address: amqp://localhost:6666, local: 49954)
[13:33:50 DBG] Endpoint Ready: rabbitmq://localhost/McShahab_DemoTransactio_bus_5emoyydyan1f7qhobdppkkw6gp?temporary=true
[13:33:50 DBG] Endpoint Ready: rabbitmq://localhost:6666/McShahab_DemoTransactio_bus_5emoyydyan1f7jiabdppkkw9bz?temporary=true
[13:33:50 INF] Bus started: rabbitmq://localhost:6666/
[13:33:50 DBG] Declare queue: name: CancelOrder, durable, consumer-count: 0 message-count: 0
[13:33:50 DBG] Declare queue: name: CreateOrder, durable, consumer-count: 0 message-count: 0
[13:33:50 DBG] Declare queue: name: GetOrder, durable, consumer-count: 0 message-count: 0
[13:33:50 DBG] Declare exchange: name: GetOrder, type: fanout, durable
[13:33:50 DBG] Declare exchange: name: CreateOrder, type: fanout, durable
[13:33:50 DBG] Declare exchange: name: CancelOrder, type: fanout, durable
[13:33:50 DBG] Declare exchange: name: Demo.TransactionalOutbox.Domain.OrderAggregate.Queries:GetOrderStatus, type: fanout, durable
[13:33:50 DBG] Declare exchange: name: Demo.TransactionalOutbox.Domain.OrderAggregate.Commands:CancelOrder, type: fanout, durable
[13:33:50 DBG] Declare exchange: name: Demo.TransactionalOutbox.Domain.OrderAggregate.Commands:CreateOrder, type: fanout, durable
[13:33:50 DBG] Bind queue: source: GetOrder, destination: GetOrder
[13:33:50 DBG] Bind queue: source: CancelOrder, destination: CancelOrder
[13:33:50 DBG] Bind queue: source: CreateOrder, destination: CreateOrder
[13:33:50 DBG] Bind exchange: source: Demo.TransactionalOutbox.Domain.OrderAggregate.Commands:CreateOrder, destination: CreateOrder
[13:33:50 DBG] Bind exchange: source: Demo.TransactionalOutbox.Domain.OrderAggregate.Queries:GetOrderStatus, destination: GetOrder
[13:33:50 DBG] Bind exchange: source: Demo.TransactionalOutbox.Domain.OrderAggregate.Commands:CancelOrder, destination: CancelOrder
[13:33:50 DBG] Consumer Ok: rabbitmq://localhost/GetOrder - amq.ctag-jT06Ly0B8--gYF2XxxxyGQ
[13:33:50 DBG] Consumer Ok: rabbitmq://localhost/CreateOrder - amq.ctag-K2-6Gcdxk8z6UPxI0q-xQw
[13:33:50 DBG] Consumer Ok: rabbitmq://localhost/CancelOrder - amq.ctag-YRlkqWCWLKPX1JpCtEThJQ
[13:33:50 DBG] Endpoint Ready: rabbitmq://localhost/CreateOrder
[13:33:50 DBG] Endpoint Ready: rabbitmq://localhost/GetOrder
[13:33:50 INF] Bus started: rabbitmq://localhost/
[13:33:50 DBG] Endpoint Ready: rabbitmq://localhost/CancelOrder
```

and the Consumer of the Events:

```bash
[13:33:47 INF] Configured endpoint OrderCreated, Consumer: Demo.TransactionalOutbox.FancyConsumer.OrderCreatedConsumer
[13:33:48 DBG] Starting bus instances: IBus
[13:33:48 DBG] Starting bus: rabbitmq://localhost:6666/
[13:33:48 DBG] Connect: guest@localhost:6666/
[13:33:48 DBG] Connected: guest@localhost:6666/ (address: amqp://localhost:6666, local: 49947)
[13:33:48 DBG] Endpoint Ready: rabbitmq://localhost:6666/McShahab_DemoTransactio_bus_hrmoyydyan1fh45qbdppkkiyy5?temporary=true
[13:33:48 DBG] Declare queue: name: OrderCreated, durable, consumer-count: 0 message-count: 0
[13:33:48 DBG] Declare exchange: name: OrderCreated, type: fanout, durable
[13:33:48 DBG] Declare exchange: name: Demo.TransactionalOutbox.Domain.Events:OrderCreated, type: fanout, durable
[13:33:48 DBG] Bind queue: source: OrderCreated, destination: OrderCreated
[13:33:48 DBG] Bind exchange: source: Demo.TransactionalOutbox.Domain.Events:OrderCreated, destination: OrderCreated
[13:33:48 DBG] Consumer Ok: rabbitmq://localhost:6666/OrderCreated - amq.ctag-53c0dDTumv3l33VqwMiSpA
[13:33:48 DBG] Endpoint Ready: rabbitmq://localhost:6666/OrderCreated
[13:33:48 INF] Bus started: rabbitmq://localhost:6666/
```

In contrast to the sample application for the outbox pattern, I did not see any logs for the Outbox, neither when the rabbitmq is up&running nor when it is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, Transactional Outbox only works with the primary (`IBus`) bus instance. Any additional bus instances when using MultiBus are unable to use the transactional outbox at this time.

#### Updated

In your event emitter, you can't use `IBus` as a publish endpoint because it isn't scoped. But you also can't just use `IPublishEndpoint` because it would probably be the *ConsumeContext* from the consumer on the command bus. The underlying wiring to get the transactional outbox isn't really setup to work that way from a consumer on one bus to producing events on another bus.

Comment: That means the IBus registered with the `services.AddMassTransit` without generic parameter, right? Because I have one primary bus, IBus, and another secondary ICommandBus, and I am using the IBus to publish my event, but it's not working.